# Mapping ids of two vectors

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors with the same elements but their order is not same. For eg

A

```
10
9 
8
```

B

```
8
9
10
```

I want to find the mapping between the two

B2A

```
3
2
1
```

How can I do this in matlab efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Matlab sort is efficient. So:

```
[~,I]=sort(A); %sort A; we want the indices, not the values
[~,J]=sort(B); %same with B
%I(1) and J(1) both point to the smallest value, and a similar statement is true 
%for other pairs, even with repeated values.

%Now, find the index vector that sorts I
[~,K]=sort(I);

%if K(1) is k, then A(k) is the kth smallest entry in A, and the kth smallest 
%entry in B is J(k)
%so B2A(1)=J(k)=J(K(1)), where BSA is the desired permutation vector

% A similar statement holds for the other entries
%so finally

B2A=J(K);
```

if the above were in script "findB2A" the following should be a check for it

```
N=1e4;
M=100;
A=floor(M*rand(1,N));
[~,I]=sort(rand(1,N));
B=A(I);
findB2A;
all(A==B(B2A))
```

Comment: +1 for the approach, but I think you got the third `sort` line wrong. Maybe you're obtaining "`A2B`" instead of `B2A`. See my answer

Comment: I guess the definition isn't clear from the problem, since in it the two are the same. I define it to be the vector satisfying 'isequal(A,B(B2A))'

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution :

```
arrayfun(@(x)find(x == B), A)
```

I tried with bigger arrays :

```
A = [ 7 5 2 9 1];
B = [ 1 9 7 5 2];
```

It gives the following result :

```
ans =

 3     4     5     2     1
```

**Edit**

Because `arrayfun` is usually slower than the equivalent loop, here a solution with a loop:

```
T = length(A);
B2A = zeros(1, length(A));
for tt = 1:T
   B2A(1, tt) = find(A(tt) == B);
end
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Could you explain why? Because from my perspective, it gives good result...

Comment: The poster asked for efficiency. `find` is not efficient to begin with, and running it for each element does not help.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `ismember` uses the `find` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. The most efficient in terms of lines of code is probably using [`ismember()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). The return values are `[Lia,Locb] = ismember(A,B)`, where `Locb` are the indices in `B` which correspond to the elements of `A`. You can do `[~, B2A] = ismember(A, B)` to get the result you want. If your version of MATLAB does not allow `~`, supply a throwaway argument for the first output.

You must ensure that there is a 1-to-1 mapping to get meaningful results, otherwise the index will always point to the first matching element.

Comment: I disagree. It's the second output argument, not the first. Please read carefully

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [Joe Serrano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790654/2586922) using three chained `sort'`s.

Another approach is to test all combinations for equality with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
[~, B2A] = max(bsxfun(@eq, B(:), A(:).'));
```

This gives `B2A` such that `B(B2A)` equals `A`. If you want it the other way around (not clear from your example), simply reverse `A` and `B` within `bsxfun`.