# Matlab, order cells of strings according to the first one

Tags: string, matlab, cell, cell-array

I have 2 cell of strings and I would like to order them according to the first one.

```
A = {'a';'b';'c'}
B = {'b';'a';'c'}

idx = [2,1,3] % TO FIND

B=B(idx);
```

I would like to find a way to find `idx`...

Comment: see also [Mapping IDs of two vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788606/mapping-ids-of-two-vectors/21790654#21790654)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be significantly faster than using `ismember` (although admittedly less clear than [@rayryeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670568/2586922)). With thanks to @Divakar for his correction on this answer.

```
[~, indA] = sort(A);
[~, indB] = sort(B);
idx = indA(indB);
```

Comment: OH. Good use of `sort`.  I had a feeling to use `sort`, but I couldn't figure out exactly how to use the other array `B`.  Nicely done +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Actually it's confusing to play with nested sortings. Sometimes I just try combinations (there are not so many) until I find that which works :-) (BTW already +1 too)

Comment: What if some elements are not common between A and B or if there is repetition of elements inside each of those cell arrays? Something like this maybe - `A = {'a';'b';'c';'d'}, B = {'b';'a';'c';'a'}`.

Comment: I guess OP might not be concerned with repetition cases, but at least not-common-elements cases could be dealt with.

Comment: @Divakar - That's a good point.  My guess is that the OP is only concerned with a permutation in ordering between `A` and `B`.  I guess we can assume that the elements in `A` will be in the elements of `B` and are unique.  If this is the case, then this method will work very well. BTW, Luis Mendo, thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Had to make a correction there in your solution, please make sure I didn't mess it up! :) Basically I tried with - `A = {'a';'b';'c';'r';'t';'u';'p'}
B = {'b';'a';'c';'t';'r';'p';'u'}` and was giving me wrong results with your original code.

Comment: @Divakar I knew trying combinations of nesting indices until one worked would end up giving me some trouble ;-) Thanks for saving me!

Answer (score 3):

Use the second output of [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).   `ismember` tells you whether or not values in the first set are anywhere in the second set.  The second output tells you where these values are located if we find anything.  As such:

```
A = {'a';'b';'c'}
B = {'b';'a';'c'}
[~,idx] = ismember(A, B);
```

Note that there is a minor typo when you declared your cell arrays.  You have a colon in between `b` and `c` for `A` and `a` and `c` for `B`.  I placed a semi-colon there for both for correctness.

Therefore, we get:

```
idx =

  2
  1
  3
```

---

## Benchmarking

We have three very good algorithms here.  As such, let's see how this performs by doing a benchmarking test.  What I'm going to do is generate a 10000 x 1 random character array of lower case letters.  This will then be encapsulated into a 10000 x 1 cell array, where each cell is a single character array.  I construct `A` this way, and `B` is a random permutation of the elements in `A`.  This is the code that I wrote to do this for us:

```
letters = char(97 + (0:25));
rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
ind = randi(26, [10000, 1]);
lettersMat = letters(ind);
A = mat2cell(lettersMat, ones(10000,1), 1);
B = A(randperm(10000));
```

Now... here comes the testing code:

```
clear all;
close all;

letters = char(97 + (0:25));
rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
ind = randi(26, [10000, 1]);
lettersMat = letters(ind);
A = mat2cell(lettersMat, 1, ones(10000,1));
B = A(randperm(10000));

tic;
[~,idx] = ismember(A,B);
t = toc;

fprintf('ismember: %f\n', t);

clear idx; %// Make sure test is unbiased

tic;
[~,idx] = max(bsxfun(@eq,char(A),char(B)'));
t = toc;

fprintf('bsxfun: %f\n', t);

clear idx; %// Make sure test is unbiased

tic;
[~, indA] = sort(A);
[~, indB] = sort(B);
idx = indB(indA);
t = toc;

fprintf('sort: %f\n', t);
```

This is what I get for timing:

```
ismember: 0.058947
bsxfun: 0.110809
sort: 0.006054
```

Luis Mendo's approach is the fastest, followed by `ismember`, and then finally `bsxfun`.  For code compactness, `ismember` is preferred but for performance, `sort` is better.  Personally, I think `bsxfun` should win because it's such a nice function to use ;).

Comment: That was just a lazy comment from me!;) +1 of course.

Comment: @Divakar - ahaha thanks :) I was literally about to push the post button when I saw your comment.  I wouldn't have posted if I saw your comment earlier.

Comment: I am glad you posted really! And always great to have explanation going there.

Comment: haha very nice and more importantly fair benchmarking! Seems like `bsxfun` lost out, but it's cute-ness stays! ;) BTW Luis's solution needed a correction, but I don't think it's gonna affect the benchmarking a lot. Also, I think benchmarking against `[~,idx] = max(bsxfun(@eq,char(A),char(B)'))` would be fairer as we are not considering not-common elements case. And you do need that `"."` for `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to jump in as it seems runtime performance could be a criteria here :)

Assuming that you are dealing with scalar strings(one character in each cell), here's my take that works even when you have not-commmon elements between `A` and `B` and uses the very powerful `bsxfun` and as such I am really hoping this would be runtime-efficient -

```
[v,idx] = max(bsxfun(@eq,char(A),char(B)'));
idx = v.*idx
```

Example -

```
A = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'
B = 
    'b'    'a'    'c'    'e'
idx =
     2     1     3     0
```

---

For a specific case when you have no not-common elements between `A` and `B`, it becomes a one-liner -

```
[~,idx] = max(bsxfun(@eq,char(A),char(B)'))
```

Example -

```
A = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'
B = 
    'b'    'a'    'c'
idx =
     2     1     3
```

Comment: Ahahahaha, I told myself that Divakar will most likely come in with a `bsxfun` solution.  I didn't think I would actually be right.  +1.

Comment: I was actually going to generate a bunch of random unique characters!

Comment: @rayryeng Go ahead! Let's see watchya got! ;)